# IntentService's onDestroy method getting called straight after onHandleIntent

Tags: java, android, intentservice, ondestroy

I have an `IntentService` that I am using to record audio via `AudioRecord` in my app.
In the `onHandleIntent` method, I call `.getInstance` of a seperate class that I used for handling the recording, and then call a couple of methods of that class.

However as soon as the intentService starts, its `onDestroy` method gets called, and the recording stops.
In the class that gets instantiated in the `onHandleIntent`, the audio is still recording, until the `onDestroy` gets called.
So surely `onDestroy` shouldn't get called until the recording is finished.

If someone could offer a suggestion as to why it is doing this, it would be much appreciated.

The code for my IntentService is below:

```
public class RecordService extends IntentService {
    public File directory;
    AudioRecord audioRecord;
    int sampleRate = 44100;
    int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    File file;
    short channels = 1;
    int bitsPerSample = 16;
    public RecordService() {
        super("Record");
    }
    ExtAudioRecorder extAudioRecord;

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.v("Record", "Record called");
        extAudioRecord = ExtAudioRecorder.getInstanse(false);
        extAudioRecord.reset();
        extAudioRecord.setOutputFile(getOutputFile("RecV2").toString());
        extAudioRecord.prepare();

        extAudioRecord.start();
        //record();
    }
    public void onDestroy(){
        extAudioRecord.stop();
        //audioRecord.stop();
        Log.v("Record", "onDestroy called, Record stopped");

    }
```

Comment: So did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `extAudioRecord.start();` is non-blocking meaning it returns immediately exiting `onHandleIntent()`. The IntentService is terminated shortly after calling `onDestroy`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639853/sync-version-of-async-method