# How to return result from java interface / similar using blocks

Tags: java, android, interface

I was wondering if I could change the way my method function, similar to [Blocks iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html).

So I have this interface create in class `API.java`

```
 public interface APIListener {
        void apiResponseSuccess(String output);

        void apiResponseFailed(String output);
    }
public APIListener listener = null;
public void myMethod{
listener.apiResponseSuccess("output");
}
```

In order to call my interface created, i have to `implements`
`API.APIListener`. and override the functions

```
@Override
    public void apiResponseSuccess(Object output) {
        Log.i("output from api",(String) output);
    }

    @Override
    public void apiResponseFailed(String output) {

    }
```

And to call it, I have to use :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        API api = new API();
        api.listener = this;
        api.myMethod();    

    }
```

But drawbacks using this, It's hard to maintain if I call many methods inside the API, because all the results will go to `apiResponseSuccess` in my class, and have to tag which one coming from. Where the iOS comes with Blocks, it becomes easier. so basically, Is there a way to return the interface methods direct when we call it. similar to this

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        API api = new API();
        api.listener = this;
        api.myMethod(
             public void apiResponseSuccess(Object output) {
             Log.i("output from api",(String) output);
            }
             public void apiResponseFailed(String output) {

            }); //so the result will go in separately inside the where the function is called.
    }
```

Comment: have you read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639853/sync-version-of-async-method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it easily.

Your api method should get APIListener as a parameter - so when you'll call it you'll have something like this:

```
api.myMethod(new APIListener() {
  @Override
  public void apiResponseSuccess(Object output) {
    Log.i("output from api",(String) output);
  }

  @Override
  public void apiResponseFailed(String output) {

  }
});
```

You can also pass more params of course:

```
api.myMethod(new APIListener() {
  @Override
  public void apiResponseSuccess(Object output) {
    Log.i("output from api",(String) output);
  }

  @Override
  public void apiResponseFailed(String output) {

  }
}, "my String", true);
```

BUT... notice that with your current implementation that the activity is the listener of your API call you'll have a memory leak!

You can solve it in several ways:

1. Don't make the listener anonymous ("ios block") but an inner static class that takes the activity as a WeakReference
2. Encapsulate the WeakReference inside your API and manage your listeners there.

Comment: So I modify `myMethod` to `public void myMethod(APIListener apiListener)`. and how to add more parameters, for example : `public void myMethod(APIListener apiListener, String param1, String param2)`. how to call it ?

Comment: Exactly like you wrote - straight forward. see my updated answer.